# FFMPEG not save logs when converting to audio format

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, subprocess, popen

The command does not save or even create a file:

**ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -f mp3 "audio.mp3" -vstats_file "log_file.log"**

And if you convert to a video file, everything normally creates and writes:

**ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -f mp3 "video.avi" -vstats_file "log_file.log"**

Goal: to pull out the time from the log file and bind it to the process bar.

There are no problems with video, everything works. But with the sound does not work.

I tried the command:

**ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -f mp3 "video.avi" >2 "log_file.txt"**
But there are other problems popping out. Since I run it all from the python using the subprocess

**ffmpegProc = subprocess.Popen(ffmpegCommand, startupinfo=startupinfo, shell=True)** 
, I can not kill the running process, because it is started with the attribute **shell=True**, and only the shell is killed.and only the shell is killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-vstats` is for video encoding statistics. When writing an audio file, there's no video encoding. Use the `-progress` option.

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -f mp3 "audio.mp3" -progress "log_file.log"
```

You'll get blocks such as these:

```
bitrate= 126.2kbits/s
total_size=7695851
out_time_ms=487944127
out_time=00:08:07.944127
dup_frames=0
drop_frames=0
speed=19.5x
progress=continue
```

Search for the last `out_time` and that's your progress status.